# How to fix The method setLatestEventInfo(Context, String, String, PendingIntent) is undefined for the type Notification

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I can't fix this error that I'm getting in Eclipse. It's an imported project. Everything else works fine except for this error:

> The method setLatestEventInfo(Context, String, String, PendingIntent) is undefined for the type Notification   MyNotificationBuilderToGingerBread.java /CANAPP/src/com/ftech/canapp/notification   line 14 Java Problem

Here's the code that I'm working on

```
package com.ftech.canapp.notification;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;

public class MyNotificationBuilderToGingerBread {

    Notification notification = null;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public MyNotificationBuilderToGingerBread(Context myContext, int icon, String ticker, String title, String info, Long timeStamp, PendingIntent pendingIntent) {
        notification = new Notification(icon, ticker, timeStamp);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(myContext, title, info, pendingIntent);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public MyNotificationBuilderToGingerBread(Context myContext, int icon, String ticker, String title, String info, Long timeStamp, PendingIntent pendingIntent, int flags) {
        notification = new Notification(icon, ticker, timeStamp);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(myContext, title, info, pendingIntent);
    }

    public Notification get() {
        return notification;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've used this wrapper for all versions:

```
public static Notification notification(Context ctx, String title, int icon,
            long when, PendingIntent pIntent, String contentTitle,
            String contentText,int flags, int defaults){
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx);
        Notification notification = builder.setContentIntent(pIntent)
              .setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(title).setWhen(when).setContentTitle(contentTitle)
              .setContentText(contentText).setDefaults(defaults).build();
        notification.flags = flags;
        return notification;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The method setLatestEventInfo(Context, String, String, PendingIntent) was deprecated in Android in a previous version and has been removed in API v23. You won't be able to use the method if you target that version of Android.

EDIT: In order to update info on a notification, you could instead use [NotificationManager.notify()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#notify%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29), which is part of API 23.